# Is it OK to mix OpenMP with python's concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor?

Tags: python, openmp

I have low level code C++ code that uses OpenMP to optimize data-parallel tasks. This is wrapped in Python using numpy.ctypes.

Is it OK to call my low level OMP using function from several threads concurrently using concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor?

It has worked for me for the last couple years, but I'm having threading problems on one target machine. I tried compiling against both libgomp and libiomp5. I intermittently experience hanging, segfaulting and correct behavior on the target in question.